# Azure Connection String Error

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string

I am getting a strange error when trying to connect to my azure instance from my local machine using our company crm. The Crm can use static library methods.

**A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The parameter is incorrect.)**

here is my connection string

```
    Server=MyAzureServer;Database=MyDatabase;Persist Security 
    Info=False;UserID=User;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=false;
```

I know its to do with the TrustServerCertificate property because if I set this to true it works but this is a security risk so dont want to do that. And as I say it works on other machines fine, Just not mine.

- If I create a new console application and use this connection string with the static library it works fine;
- If I use our Company CRM to connect it fails

I have installed .NET core recently so not sure if this has anything to do with it?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply @evilSnobu, I'll have to look into that, I wouldnt exactly say I'm an expert on certs etc. Strange how I can use the same conn string in a test app in Visual Studio and dont get an error at all, do you know why this would be?  Thanks

Comment: Is your test app running on the CRM server? The TLS cert is validated against the root CA of the machine running the code (e.g. `sqlConn.Open()` or whatever).

Comment: No - test app running on my local machine - the static library component that does the actual send to azure is also on my local machine. It takes the conn string as a string parameter. I only get the error when I run my Crm and it calls the library method - the CRM is also a local install. If I run the CRM from the server and do the same thing it works fine.

Comment: Maybe you're missing an extra file with some cert bundle? Usually .pem or .pfx or .crt.

Comment: Thanks I'll do some further checking.. I have installed a load of new stuff recently, npm, dotnet core sdk, wonder of this has done something wierd to my machine.  Thanks for helping

Comment: Not really. I'd rather check what's different in the cert store in your machine vs the one that works. Maybe it expects the intermediate cert in a different location. If you can step through what the assembly does when it calls the database endpoint.. that will tell the full story.

Answer (score 2):

The machine calling the database does not have the CA Root or the leaf cert installed and fails to verify the TLS certificate presented by Azure SQL in the handshake.

In your case that would be the CRM server missing the cert(s).

I'm assuming you're talking about Azure SQL so the root and leaf is whatever gets returned in a TLS handshake to

```
https://{your-database-name}.database.windows.net
```

In my case that's **[Baltimore CyberTrust Root](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm)** and **[Microsoft IT SSL SHA2](https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm)**. I'm not adding thumbprints since certs have limited lifetime and future googlers could be thrown off.

Open *Dev Tools in Chrome → Security → View Certificate* to inspect the chain.

[image: Certificate chain]

Comment: Ok so it's none of the above, i'm leaving this answer here since it's an entirely plausible scenario :)